# Find the Unique Colors from an UIImage in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, uiimage, histogram

I am a newbie in IOS development. I Already tried with the following code for getting unique colors from an UIImage, But it's not working. And my image size is `360x480`.

```
    let data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)
    var dataType = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data)
    var rgb: RGB = (red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)

    var RedOffSet: UInt8 = 0xE0
    var GreenOffSet: UInt8 = 0xF0
    var BlueOffSet: UInt8 = 0xE0


    var RGBHistogram = [Int](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
    var Top10Colors = [UInt](count: 10, repeatedValue: 0)
    let size: Int = 4 * pixelsWide * pixelsHigh
    var dtIndex = 0


    while(true)
    {
        if(dtIndex < (size - 4)){

            //let alpha   = dataType[0]

            let red     = (dataType[dtIndex + 1]) & RedOffSet
            let green   = (dataType[dtIndex + 2]) & GreenOffSet
            let blue    = (dataType[dtIndex + 3]) & BlueOffSet

            let index = red << 2 | green >> 1 | blue >> 5
            let i: Int = Int(index)
            RGBHistogram[i] += 1
            //dataType += 4
            dtIndex += 1
        }
        else {

            print("Histogramm Created and Exited from Loop Here")
            break;
        }
    }

    //find the Top 10 Colors from Histogramm
    var prevMax = 0
    var max = 0
    var maxJ = 0

    for var indexI in 0 ..< 10 {
        max = 0
        for var indexJ in 0 ..< 1024 {

            if indexI != 0 {

                if (RGBHistogram[indexJ] > max) && (RGBHistogram[indexJ] < prevMax) {
                    max = RGBHistogram[indexJ]
                    maxJ = indexJ
                }
            }
            else {

                if RGBHistogram[indexJ] > max {
                    max = RGBHistogram[indexJ]
                    maxJ = indexJ
                }
            }
        }
        Top10Colors[indexI] = UInt(maxJ)
        prevMax = RGBHistogram[maxJ]
    }

    //Change the Top 10 Cors to its RGB

    for(var index = 0; index < 10; index += 1) {

        let red     = (Top10Colors[index] >> 2) & UInt(RedOffSet)
        let green   = (Top10Colors[index] << 1) & UInt(GreenOffSet)
        let blue    = (Top10Colors[index] << 5) & UInt(BlueOffSet)

        rgb.red = CGFloat(red)
        rgb.green = CGFloat(green)
        rgb.blue = CGFloat(blue)

        cpUniqueColorsList.append(UIColor(red: rgb.red, green: rgb.green, blue: rgb.blue, alpha: 1.0))
    }
```

with this code I am only getting 2 colors from any image,  instead of all the unique colors, so kindly help me out on how to resolve this issue.

I have tried the same code using C++, and it is working fine.

Thanks in advance
Sharief

Answer (score 0):

UIColor is based on component values from 0..<1.0, not 0..<256.  Divide each component by 255.0 and you should get better results.  Also note that your hashing algorithm eliminates red completely `(0xff & 0xe0 << 2) = 0` since that math will be done as UInt8.

Comment: Just an FYI: In apps linked against iOS 10 or later, the colour is specified in an extended colour space, and the input value is never clamped so the floating point value can go below 0 or above 1.0. Docs: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621925-init

Comment: Yeah, but in this case, since he's going from ARGB8 to UIColor, they're always in the range 0.0 ..< 1.0.